# Android NDK/JNI: Build shared library using static library

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I need to build a shared library, which will be used in an Android application sample.
This shared library must use methods that are contained in a previous static library...

I have 2 projects:

-- **C++ Project** (used to build the static library .a using the NDK).

-- **Android library** ; with JNI interface.

I followed this tutorial:
http://tariqzubairy.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/use-of-prebuild-static-library-compiled-with-android-toolchain/

The hierarchy of my Android library project is:

Project Root

- src
- jni

  - **include**

    - myHeader.hpp
  - **prebuid** (contained the .a library)

    - mylib.a
  - jni.cpp
  - Android.mk

myHeader.hpp file:

```
char* myMethod(int a, int b);
```

jni.cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/myHeader.hpp"

extern "C"
{
    jstring Java_my_package_myMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, jint a, jint b);
}
...
```

android make file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#Build module for static library

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE                        := my_static_lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES                     := prebuild/mylib.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES             := include/myHeader.hpp
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)


#Build module for jni wrapper

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := jni_wrapper_lib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := jni.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES              := my_static_lib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I try to build the JNI project, I got the following error:
Undefined reference to "myMethod(int a, int b)"

Can someone explained me why I got this error ?

Thanks a lot for your time;

Answer (score 0):

Even though I can't put my hand on any related documentation, it *seems* to me that the `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` should point to the folder instead of the file:

```
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := include
```

It would seem logic, as this flag is an equivalent of the usual `-I` CFLAG, which would have been `-Iinclude` and not `-Iinclude/myHeader.hpp`

Tell me if this solved your problem!

Comment: I just deleted this line. I still have the error "undefined reference", but this time it's not about a class, it's about an object that I declared inside a method in my static library !

It's happening when I'm trying to build the shared library using the static one; so I guess the problem is during the link process when I built my static library (c++ sources) ?